# Does Asynchronous module loading offer any gain when loading of a module is inevitable?

Tags: requirejs, amd

AMD modules like [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) can help save a network round trip if there arises a case when loading a module is never required. But would it offer any gains at all when loading a module is inevitable, for example loading common libraries like jQuery and bootstrap javascript files.

Answer (score -1):

When loading a module is inevitable, requirejs provides no gains at all. On the contrary it hurts your performance. That is because loading a resource by script is always slower that loading it through the html parser. So in general scripts loaded through `<script>` tag will be faster than loading it via ajax and then `eval`ing it. Same goes with the `<img>` tags, and for that matter any static resource.

AMD offers benefits only when your scripts are too large and you want to load your modules step by step rather than all at once. If there arises a case when a module might not be needed at all, that is win in terms of network roundtrip and bandwidth, in those cases it should certainly be used.

Libraries like jQuery and bootstrap are required usually upfront, there is no point delegating them to AMD.

Comment: You should write a blog post instead of asking an opinion-based question you're intending to answer yourself. Some references, benchmark results would be nice if you want to be taken seriously. Disclaimer: I'm not the downvoter (...yet, still considering)

Comment: Stackoverflow states that one can share knowledge by answering his own question. Besides not every stackoverflow question is fraught with benchmarks and results. I will post references that substantiates my claim. And it is not a matter of opinion, AMD is slower that script tag, wait for a while for refereneces.